# Query to mongodb are slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When i make query to **mongodb** using **Mongoose** it will take a lot of time.

[image]

My code is :

[image]

Even there is no much data in the collection. It's only 3-4 documents. 
this gif will show what my problem is. Due to this late processing, there is a glitch between loading of the page and retrieving data in my application

[image]

Chrome Devtool's output is like :

[image]
 I have a mongodb server on  [compose](https://compose.com/).

- Is it normal or i am doing something wrong ?
- How to decrease the time taken in query processing by the server ?
- If i use [socket.io](http://socket.io) is this problem will solved ?

Back-end   : **ExpressJS**

Front-end  : **AngularJS**

Comment: When there are only 3-4 documents in de database it's not normal :) Can you check the processing time for mongo when using a UI tool (or use the mongo shell). Could it be the connection between the mongodb / backend host's ? Also make sure there is an index on the "companyId" field, not really needed for 3-4 document's, but i expect you want more documents in that collection ;-)

Comment: something strange, 'find' in such small collection can't take that long, 990ms

Comment: thats why i am worried :( @johnlowvale

Comment: I tried to get query execution time in mongo shell but i didn't find anything related to time there. Is there any specific way or tool in order to get total execution time of a query ? @HoefMeistert

Comment: you can try out [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/)